# explain 12 pulse rectifier output and filter circuit?

Tags: filter, rectifier, passive-filter

Parameter

1. 3 phase 115/200 volts AC Input
2. 200-amp output
3. Input Frequency is 400
4. DC output is 28 volts
5. Output ripple is 1.5-volt maximum

**Question** : on transformer secondary side it is star and delta connection with rectifiers (check the link: [12 pulse rectifier](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Tchandra_Sekar/publication/261395215/figure/fig2/AS:413865004290052@1475684514584/Transformer-Connection-for-Quasi-12-pulse-Operation.jpg)). In this transformer, secondary first is 12.5 volt and second secondary voltage is 21.6 volts approx. which is line to line is 21.6 and phase to phase is 12.5 in star connection.for all transformers it is like this.

Now my question is I want to know the output voltage of the rectifier circuit. can someone explain to me how to calculate output voltage?

**2nd question**: the filter circuit which you can see in image is what type of circuit? you can see the value of capacitors like c5 is 4uf, c4 800uf, c6 40uf, c7 0.22uf, L is 8uH, and resistance is 60 ohm. **how this capacitor value calculated?**?

Please explain if you know anything about the circuit. b1 is fan.

[image]

Comment: This looks like homework with no attempt at a solution and so is very likely to be voted to close. You need to show what you do understand and where you are stuck. Use 2 x <Enter> for paragraph breaks.

Comment: I have try for the solution but I am stuck in the the output voltage of rectifier unit, I am not getting any proper solution for this.

Comment: Simulate it if you don’t know how to calculate it.